# Turn the values of a dictionary to strings

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form: `{0: [2.0,1.0], 1: [4.0,3.0], 2 [6.0,5.0]}`. How can I turn it in an effective way (i.e. without using a for loop) into this: `{0: '2.0/1.0', 1: '4.0/3.0', 2 '6.0/5.0'}`, so the numbers in each list are turn into a string of their ratio. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean without a for loop?  what makes you say that it is not an "effective" way?  the only other way is to manually refer to each key in the dict.

Comment: I mean doing a for loop and replacing each key one by one is the most obvious way to do it, but also the slowest. I was wondering if there is a faster way, using some built-in function or something.

Comment: what you are asking for is by definition impossible, and doesn't really make sense.  even if there were some native functions to transform dicts at the native level, there's no way it would be written for this specific use case.  If you need that kind of performance, you'd probably go to writing a c module to call from your script.  And really, it's highly unlikely this would ever matter, or be anywhere close to being your bottleneck.  Even if you were writing some kind of time critical app processing enormous amounts of data.

Comment: I was actually looking for a list comprehension solution which is faster than a for loop. I got my answer below.

Comment: It does perform faster in my case. I am not sure about in general

Comment: I meant in my real situation (I have a few hundred thousands entries in my dictionary, not just 2). I would not choose a winning answer if I wasn't happy with the performance of that answer.

Comment: Again, no it does not: https://repl.it/repls/FrightenedConsiderableTrace#main.py  If you were looking for a comprehension, you should just say so.  There are plenty of good reasons to use a comprehension.  "Performance" is not one of them

Comment: Look the solutions works for me faster, I have no reason to argue as long as I got the answer I was looking for. It's fine if you don't believe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this with `toolz.dicttoolz`

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import valmap
dc={0: [2.0,1.0], 1: [4.0,3.0], 2:[6.0,5.0]}
newdc=valmap(lambda x: f'{x[0]}/{x[1]}', dc)
print(newdc)
```

See helpful info about `valmap` here: [link1](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/blob/ea3ba0d60a33b256c8b2a7be43aff926992ffcdb/toolz/dicttoolz.py#L71), [link2](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.valmap). Also you can try with a dictionary comprehension:

```
newdc={k: f"{x[0]}/{x[1]}" for k,x in dc.items()}

print(newdc)
```

Both outputs:

```
{0: '2.0/1.0', 1: '4.0/3.0', 2: '6.0/5.0'}
```

Timings:

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import valmap
dc={i:[2.0,1.0] for i in range(100000)}  

#Option 1#####
newdc=valmap(lambda x: f'{x[0]}/{x[1]}', dc)

#Option 2#####
newdc={}
for k,x in dc.items():
    newdc.update({k:f'{x[0]}/{x[1]}'})


#Option 3#####
newdc={k: f"{x[0]}/{x[1]}" for k,x in dc.items()}
```

Doing 10 runs of the script and timing the options you will get:

- *Option 1*: `0.7421236000000135`
- *Option 2*: `0.7514457999996011`
- *Option 3*: `0.602290400000129`

So the `valmap` reduces the time but not as significant as the dictionary of comprehension.

**Edit:**
After a discussion and a lot of tests with [user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242), we came up to the conclusion that making the comprehension dictionary could be the best way to solve your problem. If you are interested, to see the code that [user120242](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120242/user120242) made to analyze the timings, with a large variety of possible solutions, see this https://pastebin.com/Zeyb28Ny.

Comment: Thank you for this! It does what I need! I am a bit confused by you initial comment. Isn't you solution faster than a for loop?

Comment: I edited the answer with timmings. My first solution is faster than a for loop, but not as a dictionary comprenhension. Hope it works for you. Maybe you could consider [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it :)!

Comment: oh, I see what it is.  I'm mutating them directly by key, but yours isn't.  That's where the number discrepency is for the for loop.  If you could post a repl.it or something similar where I can replicate that'd be great.  I'd like to know too.

Comment: tl;dr there's actually basically no difference.  mutating in place with for loop can be slightly faster, although you could say it's not a fair comparison.  comprehension makes a shallow copy in almost no difference in time.

Answer (score 2):

The easier seems to be a list comprehension, and access the values by index if the 2 first are always the good ones

```
d = {0: [2.0,1.0], 1: [4.0,3.0], 2: [6.0,5.0]}
res = {k:  f"{val[0]}/{val[1]}" for k,val in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dict comprehension which is faster than a for loop.

```
d = {0: [2.0, 1.0], 1: [4.0, 3.0], 2: [6.0, 5.0]}
d = {key: f"{value[0]}/{value[1]}" for (key, value) in d.items()}

print(d)
>>> {0: "2.0/1.0", 1: "4.0"/3.0", 2: "6.0/5.0"}
```

That being said, you should not worry about performance if your dictionary only has a handful of entries.

You can specify the precision of the display to one decimal by writing `"f{value[0]: .1f}/{value[1]: .1f}"`.

Comment: That is not what the OP ask

Comment: I actually have a lot of entries. However this doesn't do what I need. I still end up with a list instead of a string and I am not sure how to further process it faster (again, without using a for loop).

Comment: it's also wrong even if it worked.  a list comprehension will not outperform a normal loop.  same iteration, except object initialization will make it slower.

Comment: It will, that's the interest of comprehensions.

Comment: have you ever tried profiling it?  what you say is impossible.  the point of comprehensions is that the code is cleaner, and expression as transformations makes for better code quality.  performance has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @user120242 I find that `lst = [n**2 for n in range(1e6)]` is 14% faster than `lst = []; for n in range(1e6): lst.append(n**2)`. I'm using n² here just so that we're not tempted to compare with `list(range(N))` directly.

Comment: The reason that is faster is due to avoidance of resizing the list to append, since the size is known ahead of time.  It does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

```
d1={1:12,2:34,3:45} #let this d1 be dict
for i in d1.keys:
    print(str(i),end="")
```